# Why isn't my generated function being executed?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a logout button as follows:

```swift
struct LogoutButtonView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var state: AppState
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Log Out") { viewModel.isConfirming = true }
        .confirmationDialog("Are you that you want to logout",
                            isPresented: $viewModel.isConfirming) {
            Button("Confirm Logout", role: .destructive, action: viewModel.getLogoutAction(state: state))
            Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {}
        }
        .disabled(state.shouldIndicateActivity)
    }
}
```

Its view model is as follows:

```swift
extension LogoutButtonView {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var isConfirming = false
        
        func getLogoutAction(state: AppState) -> () -> Void {
            print("Inside getLogoutAction")
            return {
                func logout() {
                    print("Inside Logout")
                    state.shouldIndicateActivity = true
                    // .. Logout Logic
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to pass down the reference of global `AppState` to the view model, that's why I am trying to generate the logout function instead of directly putting that in my view model.

Why is it not printing "Inside Logout"? How does Swift work in terms of `Functional Programming`? What's the correct approach to update/access global `AppState` from the local view model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that you never call `logout()`.

It's true that you return the function on a button tap, but you don't call the returned (`logout`) function. So it's never executed.

Comment: The button calls `getLogoutAction()`. `getLogoutAction()` returns a function which you never call. You have more than one question here and I am answering the one you asked in the title.